# All traces lost after migration to SpringBoot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

I have an issue related to traces after the migration of a Sping CLoud Stream app to SpringBoot 3.

The code of the app is just in one class:

```
package com.example.micrometer;

import io.micrometer.observation.ObservationRegistry;
import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamReactiveConsumerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamReactiveConsumerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(StreamReactiveConsumerApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Remember about calling <.subscribe()> at the end of your Consumer<Flux> bean!");
        log.warn("Remember about finishing the span manually before calling subscribe!");
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<Flux<Message<String>>> channel(Tracer tracer, ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        return flux -> flux.doOnNext(msg -> log.info("<ACCEPTANCE_TEST> <TRACE:{}> Hello from consumer",
                tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId()))
                .subscribe();
    }

}
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: stream-reactive-consumer
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        channel-in-0.destination: myinput
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            functions:
              kafkaStreamCountWords:
                configuration:
                  client.id: client-id-kafkaStreamCount

# For tests
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}] %logger{36} : %msg%n'
```

Please note I did add the logging pattern in application.properties, as well as having the context-propagation library

Despite of

https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#instrumentation_of_reactive_libraries

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide

However, all trace are lost.

Could you please help?